# Remove Row in subclassed QSQLTableModel not updating database

Tags: python, qt, row, subclassing, qsqltablemodel

I have subclassed `QSQLTableModel` to control different display stuff in Table View (such as red color for negative values, dynamic number of decimal digits, etc..) and that works fine.

When I've tried to remove a row the method is not working, not deleting row in the underlying db.

```
class CustomSqlTableModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, table, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSqlTableModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setTable(table)              
        self.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit) #OnFieldChange
        self.select()
           
    def data(self, index, role):
        # here several ifs to control display they work fine in TableView
        # even if I delete them and just leave out the bellow standard line it will not remove the row
  
        return QSqlTableModel.data(self, index, role)
  
    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False

        return QSqlTableModel.setData(self, index, value, role)

model = CustomSqlTableModel(db=my_conn, table='my_table')
print(model.rowCount())  # returns the number of rows

a = model.removeRow(2)
print(a)  # returns True

b = model.submitAll()
print(b)   # returns True

c = model.select()
print(c)  # returns True

print(model.rowCount())  # returns the same number of rows
```

If I delete the `data` and/or `setData` reimplementation of the `QSqlTableModel` the `removeRow` does work and deletes the row from the database.

But if in the `data()` method I just leave the standard line replicating the Base class method the `removeRow` will also not work. So it must be something very basic in the subclassing that I am doing wrong.

I've seen in other responses hints that the EditRole and/or Record() method should be considered in the `data()` method reimplement but I could not figure that out.